# Custom admin link in Ghost causes refuse to connect error

Tags: server, nginx-config, ghost-blog

I am using Ghost Version 4+.

I created a custom admin link by customizing my config.production and now I am successfully redirected to my subdomain admin.mysite.com, but the problem is that everything is working fine but it refuses to connect in editing sections. I have attached a screenshot for reference.

[Reference image to the error being shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGnSP.png)

It's basically a frame showing "refused to connect" earlier which was working fine and showing a preview of all functions of the site in real time.
This was working fine on my main link - mysite.com/ghost but refuses to connect since I changed my config to a new link admin.mysite.com

This is my config file ->

```
{
  "url": "https:/mysite.com",
  "admin": {
    "url": "https://admin.mysite.com/"
  },
  "server": {
    "port": 2369,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
```

Important notes to consider :

- When I open my subdomain(admin.mysite.com) it shows default Nginx page, so I used Cloudflare redirect to point it to admin.mysite.com/ghost which holds the admin area after changing my configuration above.
- I have set my subdomain by an A record pointing to the IP address of my server. What I have not done is configuring Nginx. This is reference information hope anyone finds any solution to why I am facing this.

My assumption is that ghost is designed to connect everything at the default link which is mysite.com/ghost, the forum of ghost shows a way to do it [Ghost Admin Security: Is there any way to redirect Admin-URL (Redirection Alternative)](https://forum.ghost.org/t/ghost-admin-security-is-there-any-way-to-redirect-admin-url-redirection-alternative/21939/3)

I am not sure if I have to configure Nginx, DNS, or Config.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Nginx :

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2369;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM URI";
    
}
```

Add this line

> `add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM URI";`

If you are using Apache

> `Header always set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM URI"`

For reference : [X-Frame-Options Mozzila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Adding this header shall add a vulnerability of embedding a webpage within an Iframe despite being from the same origin.